# Simplifying the following mathematical expression using a computer?

Tags: math

I have this following beastly expression typed up very nicely in LaTeX formatting, as you can see. What is the easiest way that I can get a computer to simplify this expression for me? I have zero programming experience. I installed sagemath but it seems pretty complicated.

$W_{(1,1)}(t,v)=\frac{-t^{-2k}v^k}{3}(\frac{v^{\frac{3}{2}}-v^{\frac{-3}{2}}}{t^{\frac{3}{2}}-t^{\frac{-3}{2}}})(\frac{v^{\frac{1}{2}}-v^{\frac{-1}{2}}}{t^{\frac{1}{2}}-t^{\frac{-1}{2}}})+\frac{t^{-2k}v^k}{4}(\frac{v-v^{-1}}{t-t^{-1}})^2+\frac{t^{-2k}v^k}{12}(\frac{v^{\frac{1}{2}}-v^{\frac{-1}{2}}}{t^{\frac{1}{2}}-t^{\frac{-1}{2}}})-\frac{t^{-k}v^k}{4}(\frac{v^2-v^{-2}}{t^2-t^{-2}}) + \frac{t^{-k}v^k}{8}(\frac{v-v^{-1}}{t-t^{-1}})^2+\frac{t^{-k}v^k}{4}(\frac{v-v^{-1}}{t-t^{-1}})(\frac{v^{\frac{1}{2}}-v^{\frac{-1}{2}}}{t^{\frac{1}{2}}-t^{\frac{-1}{2}}})^2-\frac{t^{-k}v^k}{8}(\frac{v^{\frac{1}{2}}-v^{\frac{-1}{2}}}{t^{\frac{1}{2}}-t^{\frac{-1}{2}}})^4+\frac{-v^kt^{k}}{4}(\frac{v^2-v^{-2}}{t^2-t^{-2}})+\frac{v^kt^{k}}{3}(\frac{v^{\frac{3}{2}}-v^{\frac{-3}{2}}}{t^{\frac{3}{2}}-t^{\frac{-3}{2}}})(\frac{v^{\frac{1}{2}}-v^{\frac{-1}{2}}}{t^{\frac{1}{2}}-t^{\frac{-1}{2}}})+\frac{v^kt^{k}}{8}(\frac{v-v^{-1}}{t-t^{-1}})^2-\frac{v^kt^{k}}{4}(\frac{v-v^{-1}}{t-t^{-1}})(\frac{v^{\frac{1}{2}}-v^{\frac{-1}{2}}}{t^{\frac{1}{2}}-t^{\frac{-1}{2}}})^2+\frac{v^kt^{k}}{24}(\frac{v^{\frac{1}{2}}-v^{\frac{-1}{2}}}{t^{\frac{1}{2}}-t^{\frac{-1}{2}}})^4$

Comment: *I have this following beastly expression typed up very nicely in LaTeX formatting, as you can see.*  and, as you may have realised by now, this site does not render LaTeX !

Comment: Wolfram Alpha is somewhat good at simplifying expressions, and can take LaTeX-like input; see for instance: `\frac{3}{2} - \frac{2}{3}` https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B3%7D%7B2%7D-%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B3%7D However, when I type in your whole expression, I get the message "WolframAlpha does not understand your query." Maybe adding explicit multiplication signs `*` instead of latex's concatenation would help it understand?

Comment: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html#experimental-mathrm-latex-parsing

Comment: Ah, so it doesn't. Dang it.

I'm not having much luck with wolframalpha.

@user8408080 I have no programming experience, although recently I did get python SymPi installed on my PC. Can you explain that module to me and how I might use it please? I'd really apprecaite it

Comment: You can also use https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/ it's basically a text based Mathematica. You can do a lot with it and it tends to simplify things normally. You can have it factor and expand as well. It's what WolframAlpha comes from basically